# Plotting a line per row of a dataframe, at given x-values, using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Using `matplot`, I can plot a line for each row of a dataframe at given *x* values. For example

```
set.seed(1)
df <- matrix(runif(20, 0, 1), nrow = 5)

matplot(t(df), type = "l", x = c(1, 3, 7, 9)) # c(1, 3, 7, 9) are the x-axis positions I'd like to plot along
# the line colours are not important
```

I'd like to use `ggplot2` instead, but I'm not sure how best to replicate the outcome. Using `melt` I can rename the columns to the desired x values, as below. But is there a 'cleaner' approach that I'm missing?

```
df1 <- as.data.frame(df)
names(df1) <- c(1, 3, 7, 9) # rename columns to the desired x-axis values
df1$id <- 1:nrow(df1)
df1_melt <- melt(df1, id.var = "id")
df1_melt$variable <- as.numeric(as.character(df1_melt$variable)) # convert x-axis values from factor to numeric

ggplot(df1_melt, aes(x = variable, y = value)) + geom_line(aes(group = id))
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Suggest you use the name `m` for matrix, not `df` which suggests that it is a data frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since ggplot2 is increasingly used as part of the [tidyverse](https://www.tidyverse.org/) family of packages, I thought I would post a [tidy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tidy_data) approach.

```
# generate data
set.seed(1)
df <- matrix(runif(20, 0, 1), nrow = 5) %>% as.data.frame

# put x-values into a data.frame
x_df <- data.frame(col=c('V1', 'V2', 'V3', 'V4'), 
                   x=c(1, 3, 7, 9))

# make a tidy version of the data and graph
df %>%
    rownames_to_column %>%
    gather(col, value, -rowname) %>%
    left_join(x_df, by='col') %>%
    ggplot(aes(x=x, y=value, color=rowname)) +
        geom_line()
```

The key idea is to `gather()` the data into tidy format, so that instead of being 5 rows × 4 columns, the data is 20 rows × 1 `value` column along with a few other identifier columns (`col`, `rowname` and eventually `x`) in this particular case).

Comment: Excellent. Thanks @Curt, both for solving the problem and for bringing `gather` to my attention.

Answer (score 2):

`autoplot.zoo` can do ggplot graphics of matrix data.  Omit the `facet` argument if you want separate panels.  The inputs are defined in the Note at the end.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(zoo)

z <- zoo(t(m), x)  # use t so that series are columns

autoplot(z, facet = NULL) + xlab("x")
```

[image: screenshot]

**Note:** The inputs used:

```
set.seed(1)

m <- matrix(runif(20, 0, 1), nrow = 5)
rownames(m) <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")

x <- c(1, 3, 7, 9)
```